# Generating SOAP Header in the web service call

Tags: ruby

I am currently working with Web Services . I have the both consumer and provider code.The provider is written in java and consumer is written in Ruby. I don't know Ruby at all.
But As part of my requirement I have to put SOAP Header with client as XML Element with value in Ruby consumer. I am currently working with SOAP4r. And driver used is SOAP::RPC::Driver. I have found that they are using send (-,-) to call the webservice. I don't see any method send in SOAP::RPC::Driver, they are calling so as part of the code. Please help me to how to add a element client in SOAP Header of Web Service.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use ruby gem SAVON for send XML via SOAP